# Unable to download deb package from repository

Tags: apt, downloads

I am writing offline installer for my software that relies on Node.js. In order to be able to install Node.js I am trying to download deb packages with all dependencies recursively from remote repository the following way:

```
$ mkdir nodejs
$ cd nodejs
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -
$ apt-get download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances --no-pre-depends nodejs=14.17.0-deb-1nodesource1 | grep "^\w" | sort -u)
```

Unfortunatelly this one fails with the following error messages:

```
E: Can't find a source to download version '2.31-0ubuntu9.3' of 'libc6:amd64'
E: Can't find a source to download version '2.31-0ubuntu9.3' of 'libc6:i386'
```

I tried to narrow down the problem by downloading specific deb package, still no luck:

```
$ apt download libc6
E: Can't find a source to download version '2.31-0ubuntu9.3' of 'libc6:amd64'
```

The most interesting thing that `libc6` is already installed:

```
$ sudo apt install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.3).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

If I specify exact version of the package then everything works like a charm:

```
$ apt-cache madison libc6
     libc6 | 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 | http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     libc6 | 2.31-0ubuntu9 | http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
$ apt download libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work without specifying the version. I'd expected that it should choose the one by default as it's done for all other packages.

I also tried to make steps to download Node.js on two fresh virtual machines with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and everything works there. I have Kubuntu 20.04.02 LTS on my local development machine. Is anything broken in it? What else can I check to figure out? `apt-cache madison libc6` shows equal results on all of them.

**UPDATE**

Here is output of `apt-cache policy libc6 libc6:i386` requested by [@N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert):

- on local machine:

  ```
  libc6:
    Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
    Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
    Version table:
   *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.3 100
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
       2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
          500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
       2.31-0ubuntu9 500
          500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
  libc6:i386:
    Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
    Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.3
    Version table:
   *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.3 100
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
       2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
          500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
       2.31-0ubuntu9 500
          500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
  ```
- on virtual machine:

  ```
    Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
    Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
    Version table:
   *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
          500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
       2.31-0ubuntu9 500
          500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
  libc6:i386:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
    Version table:
       2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
          500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
       2.31-0ubuntu9 500
          500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you have locally installed versions of libc6 with higher versions.
You have to downgrade them to [official versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libc6) with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc6:i386=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```